# how to merge this two method together using functional programming in java

Tags: java, functional-programming

I need to merge these two method together using functional programming, but I am not familiar with it, is there anyway to do it?

```
private String getCsvHeader(Object obj) {
    Field[] fields = obj.getClass().getFields();
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    String prefix = "";

    for (Field field : fields) {
        sb.append(prefix).append(field.getName());
        prefix = ",";
    }
    return sb.toString();
}

private String getCsvString(Object obj) throws IllegalAccessException {

    Field[] fields = obj.getClass().getFields();
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    String prefix = "";
    for (Field field : fields) {
        sb.append(prefix).append(field.get(obj));
        prefix = ",";
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Comment: so the only thing that is different is `sb.append(prefix).append(field.get(obj));` so you could create a new method with a boolean and if getString then do it this way other wise do it the other way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like Scary Wombat said, It will be like that :

```
private String getCsv(Object obj, boolean isHeader) throws IllegalAccessException
    {
        Field[] fields = obj.getClass().getFields();
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        String prefix = "";
        for (Field field : fields)
        {
            if (isHeader)
            {
                sb.append(prefix).append(field.getName());
            }
            else
            {
                sb.append(prefix).append(field.get(obj));
            }
            prefix = ",";
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Really late to this party, but another possible option could be to create a method eg., `getFieldString` to accept a `Function` functional interface as follows, thus abstracting the behaviour outside the function and keeping it generic.

```
private String getFieldString(Object obj, Function f){
    Field[] fields = obj.getClass().getFields();
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    String prefix = "";
    for (Field field : fields) {
        sb.append(prefix).append(f.apply(field));
        prefix = ",";
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

We can then supply the behaviour during invocation.

```
Function<Field, String> f1 = (field) -> field.getName();
Function<Field, Object> f2 = (field) -> field.get(obj);

fc.getFieldString(obj, f1);
fc.getFieldString(obj, f2);
```

In this manner, the method `getFieldString` can be reasonably shielded from needing to be modified if in case in future a new requirement comes up.